# Expansion coefficients of an orthonormal basis must satisfy $c_n n^{1/2}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for $\sum|c_n|^2$ to converge.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, orthonormal

Expansion coefficients with respect to an orthonormal basis must satisfy $c_n n^{1/2}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ in order that $\sum|c_n|^2$ may converge. Is this true or false? Give a proof or counter-example.

Hint: Consider the sequence defined by $n^{-1/3}$ when $n$ is a perfect square, $c_n=0$ otherwise. I'm not sure how to use this hint, any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I = \{ 4^k \}_{k=0}^\infty$. Define $c_n = {1 \over \sqrt{n}}$ if $n \in I$, and $c_n = 0$ otherwise.

Then $\sqrt{n} c_n = 1$ infinitely often, hence $\sqrt{n}c_n$ does not converge to zero.

But $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |c_n|^2 = \sum_{n \in I} |c_n|^2 = \sum_{n \in I} {1 \over n} =\sum_k {1 \over 4}^k = {1 \over 1-{1 \over 4}}$.

Comment: no doesn't $\sum |c_n|^2 = \sum \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ ?

Comment: @johnmangual: No, that was the whole point of defining $I$ and $c_n$ the way I did above. Note that $c_n$ is mostly zero, and only non-zero when $n$ is a power of $4$.

Comment: is this the Cesaro sum or something? I don't think spacing the non-zero values changes the values of $c_n$.

Comment: @johnmangual: No? This is just a straight summation. Given any sequence $a_n \to 0$, I can always select a summable subsequence.

Comment: I understand everything except the last line, how come for $c_n$ we have $I$ in the sum?

Comment: @1233dfv: I don't understand your question. $I$ is a set of indices ($1,4,4^2,...$) and $c_n $ is zero **except** for these indices when they take the value ${1 \over \sqrt{n}}$ (so, $c_n$ looks like $(1, 0,0,0,{1 \over 2},0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,{1 \over 4},0,...)$).

Comment: I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In that case $c_n \sqrt{n} = n^{1/2 - 1/3} = n^{1/6} \to \infty $ however, $\sum  n^{-2/3} = \sum k^{-4/3} < \infty $.

Here we sum over $n \in \{ 1,4,9,16,\dots\}= \{ k^2 : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ or just $n=k^2$.

---

I graphed the function $f(t) = \mathrm{Re}\left[\sum k^{-1/3}e^{2\pi i k^2 t}\right]$ on $[0,1]$.  It is rather chaotic.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the part "however, $\sum n^{-2/3}=\sum k^{-4/3}\le \infty$"

Comment: @1233dfv I was stuck there too.  Either you add all the $n$ which are perfect squares or finally I decided $n = k^2$.